# Help with electrodynamics and subcript handling

Tags: electromagnetism

We are learning electrdynamics and maxwell eqation. I understand how this euation of divegence makes sense

$\nabla \cdot E = \partial_i E_i = 2\pi\rho$

is just

$\partial_x E_x + \partial_y E_y + \partial_z E_z = \rho$

I can see how repeated indices are just summed over, but for the equation (curl)

$\nabla \times \vec E = \hat{e_i} \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j E_k$ ...(1)

gives

$\hat i ( \partial_y E_z -  \partial_z E_y ) - \hat j (\partial_x E_z -   \partial_z E_x) + \hat k (\partial_x E_y -  \partial_y E_x )$ ...(2)

Can someone show me how to "visualise" tis result please? I have the definition of $\epsilon_{ijk}$

$\epsilon_{ijk} = +1$ if $(i,j,k) = (1,2,3), (2,3,1) ,  (3,1,2)$ and
$-1$ if $(i,j,k) =  (3,2,1), (1,3,2) ,  (2,1,3)$ and $0$ otherwise.

Can someone help me visualise this please. Like if i you tried to epand it? I can't see how to get (2) from (1). I just cant se all the steps. Thanks.

Comment: So what you can do is simply plug in every possibility and then sum them together. There are only 6 non-zero combinations with your definition of $\epsilon_{ijk}$, e.g. 1. $i = x, j = y, k = z$, 2. $i = x, j = z, k = y$, 3. $i = y, j = x, k = z$, 4. $i = y, j = z, k = x$, 5. $i = z, j = x, k= y $ 6. $i = z, j = y, k= x$. Try plugging these in and see if you get the same result

Comment: I'l try but i am still new to subscipts and summation - i cant see how it all works. thanks i'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it might help if we did the whole thing explicitly. I'm sure you know that
$\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i }$. Considering the definition of the Levi-Civita symbol, and the equation for the curl of $E$ (equation 1 above), we get

$\nabla \times \vec E = $

$e_1 \epsilon_{111} \partial_1 E_1 + e_1 \epsilon_{112} \partial_1 E_2 + e_1 \epsilon_{113} \partial_1 E_3 + e_1 \epsilon_{121} \partial_2 E_1 +e_1 \epsilon_{122} \partial_2 E_2 + e_1 \epsilon_{123} \partial_2 E_3 +$

$e_1 \epsilon_{131} \partial_3 E_1 + e_1 \epsilon_{132} \partial_3 E_2 + e_1 \epsilon_{133} \partial_3 E_3 + e_2 \epsilon_{211} \partial_1 E_1 + e_2 \epsilon_{212} \partial_1 E_2 + e_2 \epsilon_{213} \partial_1 E_3 + $

$e_2 \epsilon_{221} \partial_2 E_1 + e_2 \epsilon_{222} \partial_2 E_2 + e_2 \epsilon_{223} \partial_2 E_3 + e_2 \epsilon_{231} \partial_2 E_1 + e_2 \epsilon_{232} \partial_3 E_2 + e_2 \epsilon_{233} \partial_3 E_3 +$

$e_3 \epsilon_{311} \partial_1 E_1 + e_3 \epsilon_{312} \partial_1 E_2 + e_3 \epsilon_{313} \partial_1 E_3 + e_3 \epsilon_{321} \partial_2 E_1 + e_3 \epsilon_{322} \partial_2 E_2 + e_2 \epsilon_{323} \partial_2 E_3 +$

$e_3 \epsilon_{331} \partial_3 E_1 + e_3 \epsilon_{332} \partial_3 E_2 + e_3 \epsilon_{333} \partial_3 E_3 $

Now, all terms with repeated subscripts in $\epsilon_{ijk}$ must vanish due to the third condition above for $\epsilon{ijk}$ so that the above reduces to

$e_1 \epsilon_{123} \partial_2 E_3 +  e_1 \epsilon_{132} \partial_3 E_2 +  e_2 \epsilon_{213} \partial_1 E_3 +  e_2 \epsilon_{231} \partial_3 E_1 + e_3 \epsilon_{312} \partial_1 E_2 + e_3 \epsilon_{321} \partial_2 E_1$

And as stated above, cyclical terms retain their sign and anti-cyclical terms receive a negative sign,

$ e_1  \partial_2 E_3 - e_1 \partial_3 E_2  
- e_2  \partial_1 E_3 + e_2  \partial_3 E_1 +
e_3  \partial_1 E_2 - e_3  \partial_2 E_1 $

Now let's use Cartesian coordinates with the usual unit vectors $ e_1 = \hat i$ , $e_2 = \hat j$ and $e_3 = \hat k $ to finally give

$\nabla \times \vec E = \hat i ( \partial_j E_k -  \partial_k E_j ) - \hat j (\partial_x E_z -   \partial_z E_x) + \hat z (\partial_x E_y -  \partial_y E_x )$

which is exactly the equation (2) you stated above.

Comment: Oh WOW! thank you so much! Thanks for effot. It makes sense now and is is easy! thanks again!!!

Comment: @Mary_Stein. That's OK. not much effort, just a lot of copy/pasting!

Comment: When using $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{j}E_{k}$ one sums over $j$ and $k$ and then to get a non-zero answer one chooses the value of $i$ to be such that it does not equal the values of $j$ and $k$ appearing.